# Can I use dtsearch in C++ under linux, if yes what APIshould i use?

Tags: c++, linux, dtsearch

I want to use **dtsearch** in my desktop application written in C++ and Gtkmm. Can i have any API or link to the API to do my thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about dtSearch Desktop, the Windows end-user product, it is not intended or licensed to be used via the API.

The dtSearch Engine for Linux (x32 or x64) on the other hand is a developer product and has C++ and Java APIs; it includes file filters for all popular file types, can search multiple indexes at the same time, each holding over 1 Tbyte. Features natural language as well as complex Boolean searching and regular expression searching. At $2500 for a three-server license (includes one year of technical support) it is probably overkill if you just have a single Desktop application to run, but for heavy duty searching inside a datacentre it's a no brainer. Fully functional evaluation downloads at www.dtsearch.com

Answer (score 0):

I used to think this would require some trickery, because I thought the dtSearch core was written against the Win32 APIs. But Mahmoud Al-Qudsi has pointed out that dtSearch is now available directly for Linux.

That said, having used both dtSearch and Solr/Lucene, I would recommend you *not* use dtSearch, unless there's some edge feature that only it can offer you. There are some nice open source search engines these days. I would suggest the main java version of Lucene, but integrating C++ with Java might be a pain. Have you checked out [CLucene](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clucene/), the C port of Lucene? Or one of the other open source search engines based on C/C++?

[Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) is another open source engine, written in C++. I haven't used it personally, but it might have enough momentum to also be worth looking into.

Comment: Not true. From the dtsearch site: "Native 64-bit and 32-bit Win / Linux APIs; .NET Spider API"